# How to solve "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInput')"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, fixtures

There are three files:

- videoPage
- videoPage.steps
- videoPage.spec.ts

videoPage:

```
import { chromium, test} from '@playwright/test'
import * as videoPageData from '../services/data/videoPage.data.json'
import VideoPageSteps from '../services/steps/videoPage.steps'
import VideoPage from '../services/pages/videoPage'

test.describe('Test suite', () => {
    
    let videoPage: VideoPage
    let videoPageSteps: VideoPageSteps

    test.beforeAll(async () => {
        const browser = await chromium.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        videoPageSteps = new VideoPageSteps(page, videoPage)

        await page.goto(videoPageData.data.baseURL, {waitUntil: 'load'})
    })

    test('Entering a search query', async () => {
        await videoPageSteps.insertQueryText(videoPageData.data.queryText)
    })
})
```

videoPage.steps:

```
import { Page } from 'playwright'
import VideoPage from '../pages/videoPage'


export default class VideoPageSteps {

  private page: Page
  private videoPage: VideoPage

  constructor(page: Page, videoPage: VideoPage) {
    this.page = page
    this.videoPage = videoPage
  }

  async insertQueryText(queryText: string) {
    await this.videoPage.getInput().isVisible()
    await this.videoPage.getInput().fill(queryText)
  }
}
```

videoPage.spec.ts

```
import { chromium, test} from '@playwright/test'
import * as videoPageData from '../services/data/videoPage.data.json'
import VideoPageSteps from '../services/steps/videoPage.steps'
import VideoPage from '../services/pages/videoPage'

test.describe('Test suite', () => {
    
    let videoPage: VideoPage
    let videoPageSteps: VideoPageSteps

    test.beforeAll(async () => {
        const browser = await chromium.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        videoPageSteps = new VideoPageSteps(page, videoPage)

        await page.goto(videoPageData.data.baseURL, {waitUntil: 'load'})
    })

    test('Entering a search query', async () => {
        await videoPageSteps.insertQueryText(videoPageData.data.queryText)
    })
})
```

Error when running the test: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getInput')**

Please help me understand

I'm looking for an error in beforeAll, but I'm not sure where I made it

Comment: `this.videoPage` is undefined. That is what causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

`videoPage` is declared but not initialized in your `test.describe` block. Also, it looks like you might have double-pasted your spec file instead of providing the POM for VideoPage.

I'd recommend using [fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures) to define your POMs, and then bring them in on the tests where you need them. EG:

```
import { test as base, Page, Locator } from "@playwright/test";

// video_page.ts
class VideoPage {
  private page: Page;

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  async getInput():Promise<Locator> {
    return await this.page.locator('input');
  }
}

// video_page_steps.ts

class VideoPageSteps {

  private videoPage: VideoPage;

  constructor(videoPage: VideoPage) {
    this.videoPage = videoPage;
  }

  async insertQueryText(queryText: string) {
    await this.videoPage.getInput().isVisible();
    await this.videoPage.getInput().fill(queryText);
  }
}

// fixtures.ts

export const test = base.extend<{
  videoPage: VideoPage,
  videoPageSteps: VideoPageSteps
}>({
  videoPageSteps: [
    async ({ videoPage }, use) => {
      await use(new VideoPageSteps(videoPage));
    }
  ], videoPage  : [
    async ({ page }, use) => {
      await use(new VideoPage(page));
    }
  ]
});

// video_page.spec.ts
import { test } from "./fixtures";


test.describe("Test suite", () => {

  test("Entering a search query", async ({ videoPageSteps }) => {
    await videoPageSteps.insertQueryText(videoPageData.data.queryText);
  });
});
```